# Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: jquery, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have added a crystal report in my asp.net webpage. When I try to add a jquery "loading control" in the same page, it shows the report but when i try to print it or export it. It returns

"server cannot set content type after http headers have been sent"

and no report is exported/ printed.
Kindly share your reviews if someone has already gone through this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem when you dynamically generate content on webpages as you may change the content type without changing it in the header (usually unintentionally having already sent the header to the browser). Most Server side languages have a facility to prevent headers being generated or sent until you have all of the dynacmic content generated. Unfortunatly I mostly use PHP and perl for web programming so don't know the asp syntax but this should point you in the right direction.